# How i can Find Difference of arrays Having different Format

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying two Find Difference in two array Both of array are in different Format

**First Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [value] => /m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [value] => /m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [value] => /m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg
        )
}
```

**Second Array**

```
Array
(
    [0] => /m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg
    [1] => /m/b/mb04-green-0.jpg
    [2] => /m/b/mb04-blue-0.jpg
}
```

I want both of Arrays is a same format to use `array_diff()` function in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the `value` column of your first array through `array_column()`, then check the difference between that result and the second array with `array_diff()`.

```php
$diff = array_diff(array_column($first, 'value'), $second);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/19tgb

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
$array_1 = array(
   "0"=> array("value" => "/m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg"),
   "1"=> array("value" => "/m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg"),
   "2"=> array("value" => "/m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg"),
);

$result_1 = array_column($array_1,"value");
print_r($result_1);
```

To get the value of column specific from the array use `array_column()` php -function

Answer (score 0):

Here is one-liner with array_shift,

```
$arr = array_map("array_shift", $arr);
```

[array_shift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) - Shift an element off the beginning of array

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/We6Vf)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => /m/b/mb01-blue-0.jpg
    [1] => /m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg
    [2] => /m/b/mb04-black-0.jpg
)
```